# Equation of the least-squares parabola for data set. (FORTRAN)

Tags: fortran, fortran90, least-squares

Original Question:

> To find the equation of the parabola
>
> y = A + Bx + Cx^2
>
> that best fits a set of n data points, the values of A, B, and C must be determined for which the sum of the squares of the deviations of the observed y-values from the predicted y-values using the equation) is as small as possible. These values are found by solving the linear system:
>
> nA + (Ex)B + (E(x^2))C = Ey
>
> (Ex)A + (Ex^2)B + (Ex^3)C = E(xy)
>
> (Ex^2)A + (Ex^3)B + (Ex^4)C = E((x^2)y)
>
> ***E = sumation notaion = capital sigma***
>
> Find the equation of the least-squares parabola for the following set of data points:
>
> DATA X / 0.05, 0.12, 0.15, 0.30, 0.45, 0.70, 0.84, 1.04 /
>
> DATA Y / 0.957,0.851,0.832,0.720,0.583,0.378,0.295,0.156 /

I'm getting a couple errors in my code and I'm just not quite sure where I'm going wrong. I hand calculated the "Data Weights (A, B, C)" from the system of linear equations.

The Error Log is:

> --------------------Configuration: FIT - Win32 Debug--------------------
>
> Compiling Fortran...
>
> C:\MSDEV\FIT.f90
>
> C:\MSDEV\FIT.f90(34): warning FOR4265: symbol M referenced but not set
>
> Linking...
>
> FIT.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _GAUSS@24
>
> FIT.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
>
> Error executing link.exe.
>
> FIT.exe - 2 error(s), 1 warning(s)

This is my current program code:

```
        PROGRAM FIT
    REAL X(8),Y(8),LIN,QUAD,WEIGHTS(3)
    EXTERNAL LIN,QUAD
    DATA X / 0.05, 0.12, 0.15, 0.30, 0.45, 0.70, 0.84, 1.04  /
    DATA Y / 0.957,0.851,0.832,0.720,0.583,0.378,0.295,0.156 /
    DATA WEIGHTS / -0.245866582919757, 4.19120539122495, 3.92469397298994 /
    CALL GENLSQ(X,Y,8,LIN,QUAD,WEIGHTS)
    PRINT *,'THE WEIGHTS ARE'
    PRINT *, WEIGHTS
    STOP
    END

    SUBROUTINE GENLSQ(X,Y,N,F,G,WEIGHTS)
    INTEGER N
    REAL X(N), Y(N), MATRIX(3,4),WEIGHTS(3)
    EXTERNAL F,G
    DATA MATRIX / 12*0.0 /
    MATRIX(1,1) = FLOAT(N)
    DO 1 I = 1, M
    MATRIX(1,2) = MATRIX(1,2) + F(X(I))
    MATRIX(1,3) = MATRIX(1,3) + G(X(I))
    MATRIX(1,4) = MATRIX(1,4) + Y(I)
    MATRIX(2,2) = MATRIX(2,2) + F(X(I)) ** 2
    MATRIX(2,3) = MATRIX(2,3) + F(X(I))*G(X(I))
    MATRIX(2,4) = MATRIX(2,4) + F(X(I))*Y(I)
    MATRIX(3,3) = MATRIX(3,3) + G(X(I)) ** 2
    MATRIX(3,4) = MATRIX(3,4) + G(X(I))*Y(I)
1       CONTINUE
    MATRIX(2,1) = MATRIX(1,2)
    MATRIX(3,1) = MATRIX(1,3)
    MATRIX(3,2) = MATRIX(2,3)
    CALL GAUSS(MATRIX,3,4,3,WEIGHTS,SINGUL)
    RETURN
    END

    REAL FUNCTION LIN(X)
    LIN=X
    RETURN
    END

    REAL FUNCTION QUAD(X)
    QUAD=X*X
    RETURN
    END
```

ANY and ALL help is much appreciated!
Thanks,
Joe

Comment: The subroutine `GAUSS` you call is not defined anywhere. Where should it come from?

Comment: Are you learning the language? If yes, be aware you are using really ancient and obsolete constructs. Otherwise Aradi is right. (Or Bállint? With Hungarian names I am never sure.)

Comment: @VladimirF: I am using it according to the usual (international) convention, not the Hungarian one, so it's Bálint. :-)

Answer (score 0):

`C:\MSDEV\FIT.f90(34): warning FOR4265: symbol M referenced but not set`

AFAICT, you never define your loop limit M.  That's sure to cause all kinds of mischief.

Answer (score 0):

You would do better to use `implicit none` and to put your procedures into a module and to `use` that module.  Instead of `external`.   The first will cause the compiler to notify you of undeclared variables.  The second will enable to the compiler to check consistency of arguments in procedure calls.

```
module my_subs

implicit none

contains

   SUBROUTINE GENLSQ
   ....
   end SUBROUTINE GENLSQ

   FUNCTION LIN(X)
   real :: LIN
   real, intent (in) :: x
   LIN = X
   end FUNCTION LIN(X)

   FUNCTION QUAD(X)
   real :: QUAD
   real, intent (in) :: x
   QUAD=X*X
   end FUNCTION QUAD

end module my_subs


program fit

use my_subs

implicit none

.....

END program fit
```